# Sending messages to Discord channel with bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am creating a bot for my Discord server.

There is a new users channel in my server. When a new user joins, I want to send a welcome message to this channel. But, I don't know how can I access to new users channel.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    # What i should do here?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`discord.utils.get`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get) or [`guild.get_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_channel). Then you can send message by `channel.send()`.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.text_channels, name="the name of the channel the bot will send message to")
    await channel.send('A new member joined.')
```

or

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = member.guild.get_channel(channel id)
    await channel.send('A new member joined.')
```